Conditional Formatting Not Applied Correctly?
I'm playing around with Conditional Formatting, but can't figure this one out.
From the setting in the image, I expect only the top three values are colored (even though the rule applies to the whole range A2:A27). But instead, the whole column is colored. Am I misunderstanding the rule?
By the way, my goal is not to do the conditional formatting in the picture per se.
For now, since I specify that the minimum value is 700, I expect everything below it would not be affected.
If this works, I will add a second 2-color gradient rule, say, darl red - light red, with max value 700 and min value 300, applied to the same range A2:A27. And a third and fourth rule, etc.
My hope is that all the colors will show up in the data.


You should have selected the third rule instead of the first one!

My goal is not to apply that gradient scale per se.
I want to get around the 3-color scale limit by creating multiple 2-color rules that lay on top of each other. But I can't even make it work as intended with just one 2-color rule.

What you are expecting is not possible, this needs VBA, if you use multiple color grade scale it will override one another, the workaround is keeping each range bracket and use the scaling however it will not be dynamic if the data changes.

I believe the interpretation of the number type is that any value less than or equal to the minimum value (700) gets the color sky blue (or whatever that color is that was selected). With this interpretation the rule is functioning as intended.

Only one color scale can be active in a range at a time. If more than one scale is defined, the one with the highest priority is active.
In this case, the color scale should be defined individually for each cell, or for groups of cells with similar values. This can be done with a macro such as the one below. The working range here is the range A1:A12, in which random values from the range [0, 10] are placed.
Formula in A1: =RANDARRAY(12,,0,10)
The table in the range D2:E7 contains a list of boundary values of the intervals and their color patterns. Color values are typed in the cells. This can be done with a macro:
Sub DefPatternColors()
    Dim patterns As Range, cell As Range
    Set patterns = Range("E2:E7")
    For Each cell In patterns
        cell.Value = cell.Interior.Color
    Next cell
End Sub

The color scales in the working range cells are defined by a macro:
Sub ColorScalesForRange()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, i As Variant
    Dim patterns As Variant, patterns1 As Variant
    Set rng = Range("A1:A12")
    patterns = Range("D2:E7").Value
    patterns1 = Range("D2:D7").Value
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    rng.FormatConditions.Delete
    For Each cell In rng
        i = Application.Match(cell.Value, patterns1)
        If IsError(i) Then i = 1
        If i = UBound(patterns1) Then i = i - 1
        DefColorScale cell, patterns(i, 1), patterns(i, 2), patterns(i + 1, 1), patterns(i + 1, 2)
    Next cell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub DefColorScale(rng As Range, minval, mincol, maxval, maxcol)
    With rng.FormatConditions.AddColorScale(ColorScaleType:=2)
        .ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = xlConditionValueNumber
        .ColorScaleCriteria(1).Value = minval
        .ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor.Color = mincol
        .ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = xlConditionValueNumber
        .ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = maxval
        .ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor.Color = maxcol
    End With
End Sub

Any change to the data requires a refresh of this definition. In this case, you can call the ColorScalesForRange macro in the worksheet's Calculate procedure:
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    ColorScalesForRange
End Sub


